# Add X number of Working days to a date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table PostingPeriod that uses a company calendar to track all working days. Simplified, it looks like this:

```
Date        Year Quarter Month Day IsWorkingDay
25.06.2015  2015 2       6     25  1
26.06.2015  2015 2       6     26  1
27.06.2015  2015 2       6     27  0
```

I have another table that contains all purchase lines with the Orderdate, confirmed delivery date from the vendor and the maximum allowed timeframe in working days between orderdate and deliverydate:

```
PurchID  OrderDate  ConfDelivery  DeliveryDays
1234     14.04.2015 20.05.2015    30
1235     14.04.2015 24.05.2015    20
```

I want to create a new column that returns the maximum allowed Date (regardless of workday or not) for each order. The usual approach (Workingdays / 5 to get weeks, multiplied by 7 to get days) doesn't work, as all holidays etc need to be taken into consideration.
As this is for a DWH that will feed an OLAP database, performance is not an issue.

Comment: You need a calendar table. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dwainsql/2014/03/30/calendar-tables-in-t-sql/ or http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/70482/ There are plenty of other examples out there.

Comment: @SeanLange - If I understand OP's question he already has one `PostingPeriod`

Comment: which version of sql server are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 - I edited the tags.

Comment: if you must take holidays into account, and skip them if i understood correctly, you should include it in your calendar table, or have a table with the holidays. Or is that taken into account on the IsWorkingDay bit?

Comment: I'm not clear - are we after OrderDate + DeliveryDays to figure out the delivery date while skipping non-working days?  Or are we calculating how many working days between the OrderDate and ConfDelivery?

Comment: So leverage the existing calendar table and get the first date after a holiday when the calculation lands on a holiday.

Comment: Sean, I'm sort of looking for the calculation...
Joe, I'm looking for the Calendar date after 20 business days. 20 Business days are about 4 weeks, so I am looking for a date that is ~30 days in the future of the order date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this by assigning each working day an arbitrary index using `ROW_NUMBER`, e.g.

```
SELECT  Date, WorkingDayIndex = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Date)
FROM    dbo.Calendar
```

Which will give you something like:

```
Date        WorkingDayIndex
-----------------------------
2015-04-27      80
2015-04-28      81
2015-04-29      82
2015-04-30      83
2015-05-01      84
2015-05-05      85
2015-05-06      86
2015-05-07      87
```

Then if you want to know the date that is *n* working days from a given date, find the date with an index *n* higher, i.e. 2015-04-27 has an index of 80, therefore 5 working days later would have an index of 85 which yields 2015-05-05.

**FULL WORKING EXAMPLE**

```
/***************************************************************************************************************************/
-- CREATE TABLES AND POPULATE WITH TEST DATA
SET DATEFIRST 1;
DECLARE @Calendar TABLE (Date DATE, IsWorkingDay BIT);
INSERT @Calendar
SELECT  TOP 365 DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY object_id), '20141231'), 1 FROM sys.all_objects;
UPDATE  @Calendar
SET     IsWorkingDay = 0
WHERE   DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Date) IN (6, 7)
OR      Date IN ('2015-01-01', '2015-04-03', '2015-04-06', '2015-05-04', '2015-05-25', '2015-08-31', '2015-12-25', '2015-12-28');
DECLARE @T TABLE (PurchID INT, OrderDate DATE, ConfDeliveryDate DATE, DeliveryDays INT);
INSERT @T VALUES (1234, '20150414', '20150520', 30), (1235, '20150414', '20150524', 20);

/***************************************************************************************************************************/
-- ACTUAL QUERY
WITH WorkingDayCalendar AS
(   SELECT  *, WorkingDayIndex = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Date)
    FROM    @Calendar
    WHERE   IsWorkingDay = 1
)
SELECT  *
FROM    @T AS t
        INNER JOIN WorkingDayCalendar AS c1
            ON c1.Date = t.OrderDate
        INNER JOIN WorkingDayCalendar AS c2
            ON c2.WorkingDayIndex = c1.WorkingDayIndex + t.DeliveryDays;
```

If this is a common requirement, then you could just make `WorkingDayIndex` a fixed field on your calendar table so you don't need to calculate it each time it is required.

Comment: Nice one with the Index.

Comment: I was on a totally different track with my approach. The row_number works perfect, thank you!
I followed your suggestion and added it as fixed field.

Comment: You should probably run tests on your own data, but unless you can leverage `WorkingDayIndex` as a static field I would expect @mxix's answer to outperform this one. I had thought the row_number inside the outer apply would cause some performance issues, but from some brief testing it doesn't appear like it does.

Comment: For documentation reasons your approach works better, and performance is not relevant when feeding a DWH that in turn feeds an OLAP cube.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from OrderDate, the Date if you advance N(DeliveryDays) WorkingDays.

If i understood correctly you want something like this:

```
select
    PurchID,
    OrderDate,
    ConfDelivery,
    DeliveryDay,
    myDays.[Date] myWorkingDayDeliveryDate
from Purchases p
outer apply (
    select
        [Date]
    from (
        select
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                ORDER BY
                    Date
            ) myDays,
            [Date]
        from PostingPeriod pp
        where
            IsWorkingDay = 1 and
            pp.date >= p.OrderDate
    ) myDays
    where
        myDays = p.DeliveryDay
) myDays
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to do something like

```
SELECT OrderDate.PurchId, OrderDate.OrderDate, OrderDate.DeliveryDays, Aux.Counter, Aux.Date
 FROM OrderDate, (SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY Date) AS Counter, Date FROM PostingPeriod WHERE IsWorkingDay = 1 ) Aux
WHERE Counter = DeliveryDays
ORDER BY 1
```

Basically, you'd need all the dates inserted in the table PostingPeriod (weekends and holidays would have a IsWorkingDay = 0, rest of the days = 1)
and this would provide you the minimal date by summing the OrderDate with the ammount of working days